# Modify bootstrap navbar?

Tags: wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, navigation

I'm having troubles with bootstraps default layout. I'm trying to change background color of active navigation items which are currently blue, but my css just won't work on it. Here's a snippet that will show up on google chrome console on if I inspect a nav item that is selected, but it wont work.

```
.dropdown-menu .active{
background:red; 
}
```

The css exists, but the link background is still blue.

As I think I'm not making myself clear, here's a demo about how the navigation looks by default. http://demo.rootstheme.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the job:

```
.dropdown-menu li.active > a {
    background-color: red;
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, white, red);
}
```

The problem was that Bootstrap's `background-image` property was overriding yours.

Comment: I've never actually understood how to use `>` in CSS, what will it do?

Comment: E > F: Matches any F element that is a child of an element E. [More info](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#child-selectors)